# Web Scraping Wikipedia - string manipulation

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio, wiki

I have managed to to scrape this wikipedia page [Oscars Nominations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards) and extract the table under "Nominees". I can get the table by the the code below:

```
wiki <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards"
text <- wiki %>% 
         read_html() %>% 
         html_nodes('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[3]') %>% 
         html_table()
```

Which outputs a 'list' as the name 'text'

```
test <- data.frame(one=unlist(text), stringsAsFactors=F)
row.names(test) <- NULL
test <- test[-16,]
nw_lst <- strsplit(test, "\n")
```

I try to put the results in a df and then remove an useless row and then 'strsplit' on the line break regex '\n' in the 'nw_lst' which outputs another list but a lot cleaner with 23 elements that corresponds to each oscar nomination with titles listed below. I then want to parse out the list into 2 df, one for the Best picture nomination and the second df with the other nominations.

```
oscr.bp <- data.frame(Best.Picture=unlist(nw_lst[[1]]), stringsAsFactors=F)
oscr.bp <- as.data.frame(oscr.bp[-1,], stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(oscr.bp) <- c("Best.Picture")
```

So here is my issue, once I separate the nominations, I would like to clean up the text. The issue is that for some reason nothing in the 'stringr' package could remove all the unnecessary text except for the movie title.

```
str_replace_all(oscr.bp$Best.Picture,pattern = "\n", replacement = " ") 
str_replace_all(oscr.bp$Best.Picture,pattern = "[\\^]", replacement = " ") 
str_replace_all(oscr.bp$Best.Picture,pattern = "\"", replacement = " ") 
str_replace_all(oscr.bp$Best.Picture,pattern = "\\s+", replacement = " ") 
str_trim(oscr.bp$Best.Picture,side = "both")
```

But when I inspect the structure of df in my environment and click the blue arrow to see vector classes and hover your mouse over the chr vector but it has weird shapes within the character vector and has this `|__truncated__` within in the string but not visible when inspecting the string in console.

I just want to know the best way to go about cleaning these strings, or another way to get just the title names for each nomination within the HTML nodes under `<ul>`  and `<li>` parse? Do not know much about basic HTML code meanings other than looking through the source code and finding what I need using selector gadget.

Comment: "it has weird shapes within the character vector" -- this is likely an encoding problem (see `?Encoding`). Have you tried the html parsing functions in package `XML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to target each individual `<td>` then use the metadata available:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards")

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//h2[span/@id = 'Nominees']/following-sibling::table[1]") %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  map_df(function(x) {
    category <- html_nodes(x, "div") %>% html_text()
    html_nodes(x, "li") %>%
      map_df(function(y) {
        html_nodes(y, "a") %>% html_attr("title") -> tmp
        movie <- tmp[1]
        nominee <- tmp[-1]
        data_frame(movie=rep(movie, length(nominee)), nominee)
      }) %>%
      mutate(category = category)
  }) %>%
  select(category, movie, nominee)
## # A tibble: 236 × 3
##        category          movie           nominee
##           <chr>          <chr>             <chr>
## 1  Best Picture Arrival (film)        Shawn Levy
## 2  Best Picture Arrival (film)       David Linde
## 3  Best Picture  Fences (film)       Scott Rudin
## 4  Best Picture  Fences (film) Denzel Washington
## 5  Best Picture  Fences (film)        Todd Black
## 6  Best Picture  Hacksaw Ridge     Bill Mechanic
## 7  Best Picture  Hacksaw Ridge      David Permut
## 8  Best Picture Hidden Figures   Donna Gigliotti
## 9  Best Picture Hidden Figures     Peter Chernin
## 10 Best Picture Hidden Figures     Jenno Topping
## # ... with 226 more rows
```

Comment: This is what exactly I was trying to accomplish. How did you get that xpath in the beginning of your code? did you use a tool or just by looking at the HTML code?

Comment: Just by looking at the code. XPath & I have a longstanding love/hate relationship.

Comment: This works fine for Best Picture, but if we look at Best Director for example, the name of the director comes first. So eventually the column "movie" contains names of people, and the column "nominee" contains movie titles.

Comment: yes. it's called "web scraping" and not "web api using" for a reason. you kinda have to know really what you're doing for the former and not so much for the latter. if you have another need @MTurgeon you should make a new question.

Comment: @hrbrmstr No need for another question. My need is fulfilled, there is now a disclaimer in the comments to your answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have a solution to the problem, but the encoding issue may still stand. The actual task is to simply get at the movie title, which is followed by the dash character.

I start with a paste of your code, except specifying that the `html_nodes` argument is xpath and not css (threw errors for me as it is in your question).

```
wiki <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards"
text <- wiki %>% 
         read_html() %>% 
         html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[3]') %>% 
         html_table()
```

Then I stop when you define Best.Picture. Coercing it into a data.frame is unnecessary, unless I'm missing something, since it's just a vector.

```
Best.Picture <- unlist(nw_lst[[1]])[-1]
```

Then I split each entry in the `Best.Picture` character vector, and apply over the split up list (each element is a vector isolating each character in each vector element). We do this to determine where the magic dash symbol is (which I just copied and pasted directly from the terminal, since the dash is not '-', but some similar symbol (this may speak the encoding issue referenced in the comment.

```
dash <- sapply(strsplit(Best.Picture, ''), function(x){which(x == '–')})
```

After we determine where the dash is located in each element of the `Best.Picture` element, we can use `substr` to truncate the vector to only the portion that we care about. If you wanted to be on the safe side, you could cut everything up to dash - 1 (which would cut the dash as well), and then use `trimws` to remove leading or trailing spaces.

```
movTitle <- substr(Best.Picture, 1, dash-2)
```